# Android: How to get the most accurate location from GPS

Tags: android, gps

I have used this code

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                500, 50, this);
```

to get my location using GPS. From what I understood, this code updates the GPS every 500milliseconds until the accuracy is about 50ms. Right? Now how do I know when it has achieved this accuracy? So that I can send the most accurate location in a text message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

500 is the minimum interval for notifications and is only a hint.

As can be seen in the [javadocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) :

the minimum time interval for notifications, in milliseconds. This field is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value.

So you can (and will) see variations on this interval (LocationListener will not always be called with an exact 500ms interval)

50 is the minDistance and according to the docs : the minimum distance interval for notifications, in meters. So this doesn't effect the accuracy, it only defines the trigger for location updates. (if you move minDistance, then a trigger occurs). As such, this does not influence the accuracy.

However, your locationlistener will return an android.location.Location, and that exposes an accuracy (the accuracy of the fix in meters)

Comment: So you are saying it doesnt actually matter how many times it updates?

Comment: The shorter the interval, the more location updates you'll get. Out of these location updates, you can pick the most accurate one. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html for some common use-cases.
I would also advise you to test this in the field, as simulate GPS location updates through the emulator is limited, and doesn't always reflect real-world situations.
Also take into account the battery-life, as constantly having the GPS enabled while requesting location updates from it can drain the battery.

Comment: ok thanks. so one more question :) I jus want to get the location once, and send it in an sms text message. Should I be making any changes? How can I make sure the SMS is sent only after the location is obtained?

Comment: I think the sms handling deserves a seperate question. However, once you have the location, stop listening for location requests by calling locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener); and send the sms. Deciding when to stop listening and when to send the sms should be handled by the logic in your locationlistener.